# Wrong SNMP ifSpeed and ifHighSpeed values from Cisco RV 110W

Tags: networking, cisco, snmp

My Cisco Small Business RV110W Router reports wrong SNMP ifSpeed and ifHighSpeed values for eth0, vlan1 and vlan2 ( 10 Mbit/s instead of 100 Mbit/s ). This causes my SNMP management software to malfunction ( graphics are capping out flat at 10 Mbits/s ). ifSpeed and ifHighSpeed values are read-only, there is no way to correct that through SNMP.

I thought that maybe these values where dynamically adjusted under load, but they don't change.

I looked through the RV110W WebGUI for maybe a misconfigured interface ( 10Mbit/s instead of 100Mbit/s ), but didn't find anything like this.

Beside, eth1 and br0 get unset values ( 0 ).

Does anybody know what is happening here ? I'm all new to SNMP. Did I miss something ?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, the more familiar you become with SNMP, the more surprised you are when you find an implementation that isn't full of bugs. Doubly so if it's labelled 'Small Business' or 'Smart'.

Comment: You [aren't the only person complaining about this](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11566061/wrong-values-ifspeed-ifhighspeed-rv110w)